# Why does this function calls offset move when I restart windows

Tags: disassembly, windows, assembly, winapi

Every time I restart windows it breaks the patch I've made to an executable where I've called a function from the dll user32.dll. Currently the offset for the function call resides at 0x76E3CDB4, but when I restart my computer it will change to some other address. Why is this and what can I do to make sure my assembly code will always call the function properly?

Comment: read about address space layout randomization aka aslr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be due to Address Space Layout Randomization 
aka ASLR (e.g. see [this overview by Symantec](https://www.symantec.com/avcenter/reference/Address_Space_Layout_Randomization.pdf))

System modules' load addresses are randomized on each boot and 
executable images' are randomized on each execution in OS > Vista

you can check that with some simple code like this

```
:\>cat aslr.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void)
{
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibraryA("user32.dll");
    if(hMod){
        printf("My Load Addr\t%p My user Addr\t%p\n" , &main,hMod);
        FreeLibrary(hMod);
    }
}
```

compiled and executed the result as follows

```
:\>for /L %i in (1,1,10) do aslr.exe

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    00121000 My user Addr   773A0000

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    00031000 My user Addr   773A0000

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    00FB1000 My user Addr   773A0000

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    002F1000 My user Addr   773A0000

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    011B1000 My user Addr   773A0000

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    011B1000 My user Addr   773A0000

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    011B1000 My user Addr   773A0000

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    011B1000 My user Addr   773A0000

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    00181000 My user Addr   773A0000

:\>aslr.exe
My Load Addr    01121000 My user Addr   773A0000
```

to be sure you patch right you should work with RVA (Relative Virtual Address)

that is get the base of module every time and add a fixed offset that you determined earlier every time

suppose you patched @ 0x12345678 and when you patched the module was loaded at 0x10000000  then you have a difference of 0x2345678

next time if the module was loaded at 0x20000000 you use the address 0x20000000+0x2345678 == 0x22345678